# How to generate a date-time array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, datetime

How do I generate this 480x1 array of date-times in Matlab?

```
1982-01-01
1982-02-01
1982-03-01
1982-03-01 
1982-04-01
.
.
.
2015-12-01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is made easy with the [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) function (introduced in R2014b) and following the documentation to [Generate Sequence of Dates and Time](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-sequence-of-dates-and-time.html).

```
% MATLAB 2019a
t1 = datetime(1982,1,1);
t2 = datetime(2015,12,1);
t = t1:t2;
t = t(:);      % Force column
```

Alternatively, you can specify the number of linearly-spaced points between two dates using the [`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) command.

```
t_alt = linspace(t1,t2,480).';
```

You can convert to the `y-M-d` format you specified with [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) as well.

```
t_format = datetime(t,'Format','y-M-d')
```

**References:**
1. [Dates and Time (in MATLAB)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html)
2. [Represent Dates and Times in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/represent-date-and-times-in-MATLAB.html)
3. [Set Date and Time Display Format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-display-format-of-date-and-time-arrays.html)
4. [Generate Sequence of Dates and Time](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-sequence-of-dates-and-time.html)